# Use Telegram Database Library (TDLib) in GCP Functions or AWS Lambda with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, telegram, serverless-framework

The main project is to have a Telegram Application that would read the groups/supergroups I am signed up for and forward all new posts to the group that I own. I need to implement it in serverless environment, meaning running through GCP Functions or AWS Lambda.

I have a solution that does that with the local setup. I had to compile TDLib for Mac OS X, but it seems I only needed "tdjson" library for using with the code provided in [this example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/python/tdjson_example.py).

```
tdjson_path = find_library("tdjson") or "tdjson.dll"
```

This solution obviously requires the script to be running in the console and the moment I shutdown the computer all forwarding stops.

I'm not very good at Python, but I can rewrite that in JavaScript. There are Node.js wrappers for TDLib, but what I can't understand is how to use/connect it to the serverless functions like Lambda and GCP Functions. Namely I can't understand whether I need to compile the library for some specific environment and where I need to store it for the Functions to be able to access it.

There is an example of setting Node environment on Lambda with [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless), but I can't seem to be able to extrapolate that to my situation.